# Convergence in the Skorokhod topology vs. u.c.p. convergence

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, skorohod-space

I was wondering whether, and, if yes, how, weak convergence w.r.t. the Skorokhod $J_1$ topology relates to u.c.p. convergence. More specifically, if we have u.c.p. convergence, does this imply weak convergence w.r.t. the Skorokhod $J_1$  topology? For the other direction, I know that Skorokhod convergence does not imply uniform convergence; however, does the same hold for u.c.p. convergence?

Of course those questions assume a stochastic processes context. I'm willing to specify this to point processes, if necessary.

I tried looking this up online and in a few textbooks on convergence of stochastic processes, but couldn't find any answers. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think ucp is the same as local uniform convergence (of nonrandom functions)

Comment: Okay, but I'm dealing with stochastic processes, so this is not nonrandom

Comment: stochastic processes are random functions on $\mathbb{R}^+$.. everything is then immediate.

Comment: So ucp implies Skorokhod, but not the other way around?

Comment: In the a.s. sense I would say yes; when dealing with weak convergence I think one would need a proof. Will look up in the literature

Comment: @Snoop Where you able to find any results on this in the literature?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think I just have that if the limit process has continuous paths a.s. then weak convergence in l.u. topology and sk. topology are equivalent. Are you interested?

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that result. However, the processes I'm working with do not have countinuous paths. The u.c.p. convergence stems from the fact that in my case, with high probability, the jumps of two processes I'm comparing are simultaneous

Comment: Alright, I'll upvote the question